# Proving a sequence inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

> Let $(a_k)_1^n$ and $(b_k)_1^n$ be two real sequences, and suppose
>   that $(b_k)$ is nonnegative and decreasing. For $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$,
>   define $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i$. Let $M = \max \{S_1,\ldots, S_n\}$
>   and $m = \min \{S_1,\ldots,S_n\}$. Prove that $$mb_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \le Mb_1$$

I am trying to prove this by assuming that $m = S_j$, so I get
$$(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_j)b_1 \le a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \cdots + a_nb_n $$
which is equivalent to
\begin{align}
& a_2(b_1-b_2) + \cdots + a_j(b_1-b_j) \\
\le {} & a_{j+1}b_{j+1} + \cdots + a_nb_n \tag 1
\end{align}
Now if the $a_i$s are all positive then it is easy since from the fact that $(b_k)$ is a decreasing sequence,
$$a_2(b_1-b_2) + \cdots + a_j(b_1-b_j) \le (a_2 + \cdots +a_j)(b_1-b_j)$$
 But we also know that $S_1 \ge S_j$, so $a_2 + \cdots + a_j \le 0$, which implies that the LHS of $(1)$ is less than or equal to $0$, and as $S_j\le S_n \Rightarrow a_{j+1} + \cdots + a_n \ge 0$, so
$$a_{j+1}b_{j+1} + \cdots + a_nb_n \ge (a_{j+1} + \cdots + a_n)b_n \ge 0$$ therefore the RHS of $(1)$ is greater than or equal to $0$, hence $(1)$ is proven. In a similar way, we can also prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \le Mb_1$.

But the problem is that $(a_k)$ is a real sequence, not a positive sequence, which means there may be negative terms in it, and I don't have any idea how to proceed. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the lower bound be $b_nm$?

Comment: Well, the original question stated the lower bound as $mb_1$, not $mb_n$...

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_1 = S_1$ and $a_i = S_i - S_{i-1}, \ i = 2, 3, \cdots, n$, we have
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \\
=\ & S_1b_1 + (S_2-S_1)b_2 + (S_3-S_2)b_3 + (S_4 - S_3)b_4 +  \cdots
 + (S_n - S_{n-1})b_n\\
=\ &S_1(b_1 - b_2) + S_2(b_2 - b_3) + S_3(b_3 - b_4)
+ \cdots + S_{n-1}(b_{n-1} - b_n) + S_nb_n.
\end{align}
Since $b_n \ge 0$ and $b_i - b_{i+1} \ge 0, \ i=1, 2, \cdots, n-1$
and $m \le S_i \le M, \ i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$, we have
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \\
\ge\ & m(b_1 - b_2) + m(b_2 - b_3) + m(b_3 - b_4)
+ \cdots + m(b_{n-1} - b_n) + mb_n\\
=\ & mb_1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \\
\le\ & M(b_1 - b_2) + M(b_2 - b_3) + M(b_3 - b_4)
+ \cdots + M(b_{n-1} - b_n) + Mb_n\\
\le\ & Mb_1.
\end{align}
We are done.

See: Abel's summation by parts

Answer (score 1):

______Editing my previous comment & extending the answer_____________

Case 1: When {$a_i$} is a sequence of positive terms.

Upper bound can be obtained easily.

Since {$b_i$} is decreasing, $b_1\geq b_i$ for all $i=1,2...n$. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_1=b_1\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=b_1S_n\leq b_1M$.

Similarly, for the lower bound,

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\geq b_1a_1=b_1m$, since $a_i>0$ for all $i$ & $S_1=a_1<S_i$ for all i.

Case 2: When {$a_i$} is a sequence of negative terms

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\leq a_1b_1$. Note that $S_1=a_1$.Since $a_i<0$ & $S_1 \geq S_i$ for all $i$, $M=S_1$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\leq Mb_1$.

Similarly, for the lower bound,

$S_n \leq S_i$ for all $i$ & $b_1 \geq b_i$ for all $i$. So $m=S_n$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i \geq b_1 \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=b_1S_n=b_1m$.

Case 3: When {$a_i$} consists of + & - terms,

Observe that $\sum -|a_i|b_i \leq \sum a_ib_i \leq \sum |a_i|b_1$

Rightmost term is the one we considered under case1 & leftmost term is the one under case 2. Since the result was proved for both cases, it trivially holds for this case as well.

Comment: hmm..but how could you know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i \le \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_1$? Because the $a_i$s can also be negative(?)

Comment: It doesn't matter. $\sum a_ib_i= a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n \leq a_1b_1+a_2b_1+...+a_nb_1=b_1(a_1+a_2+...+a_n) $

Comment: What if we take $a_1 = -3, a_2 = -2, a_3 = -1, b_1 = 3, b_2 = 2, b_1 = 1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{3} a_ib_i  = -14$, however $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_1 = -18$, a contradiction? But the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i \le Mb_1$ is still true though ($-14 \le (-3)(3)$).

Comment: Yeah correct. I missed that point. Editing my answer to indicate the case where {$a_i$} is a sequence of positive terms.But, according to your example, $m=-6$ & $b_1=1$ so that $mb_1=-6$. In this case, it can't be true that $mb_1 \leq \sum a_ib_i=-18$ .

Comment: Ups sorry...I wrote $b_1 = 3, b_2 = 2$, and $b_1 = 1$ again in my previous comment, where the latter should be $b_3$ instead of $b_1$...so $mb_1 = -18 \le \sum a_ib_i = -18$, which is still true I guess.

Comment: I edited the comment & proved the result considering 3 cases.